# Plot the following function

Tags: plotting

[image]

Please provide the mathematica code that plots this function for structural dynamics problem,

Comment: The function is barely readable. If you can't be bothered to get a good picture, why should people bother to give you working code?

Comment: you are right, but i can see the picture clearly, i'm wondering if others cant see it clearly, thanks.

Comment: do you need help learning to type or what?

Comment: I guess asking you to [take the tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour), or maybe even ["how to ask a question"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) would be futile.

Comment: Tn := 2 s;
td := 1 s
Please help im still a beginner at mathelab, can someone correct for me this?
Plot[t/td - (1/2 Pi)*(Tn/td)*Sin[2 Pi*(t/Tn)], {t, 0, td},
 Cos[(2*Pi/Tn)*(t - td)] + (1/2*Pi)*(Tn/td)*
   Sin[(2*Pi/Tn)*(x - td)] - (1/2*Pi)*(Tn/td)*
   Sin[(2*Pi*(t/Tn)) {t, 0, 10}]]

Comment: Take a look at [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[t];
Tn = 2;
td = 1;
f[t_, td_] := Piecewise[{
    {t/td - 1/(2 Pi) Tn/td Sin[2 Pi t/Tn], 0 <= t <= td},
    {Cos[2 Pi/Tn (t - td)] + 1/(2 Pi) Tn/td Sin[2 Pi/Tn (t - td)] - 
      1/(2 Pi) Tn/td Sin[2 Pi t/Tn], t > td}
    }];
Plot[f[Tn t,td],{t,0,5},Exclusions->None,Frame->True,
   FrameLabel->{{"Rd(t,td)",None},{"t/Tn","My HW plot"}},
   GridLines->Automatic,GridLinesStyle->LightGray,BaseStyle->12,
   ImageSize->400]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much i appreciate it :D

Answer (score 2):

Start by defining your function using the `Piecewise` function.  We can do it several different ways, but here is a simple one:

```
tn = 2;
td = 1;
rd = Piecewise[{
   {t/td - 1/(2 π) tn/td Sin[2 π t/tn], 0 <= t <= td},
   {Cos[2 π / tn (t - td)] + 
     1/(2 π) tn/td Sin[2 π / tn (t - td)] - 
     1/(2 π) tn/td Sin[2 π t/tn], t > td}}, 0]
```

Notice that we are not using `:=` and we are defining `rd` without any arguments.  You need to know the difference between `=`, `:=`, so look them up in the documentation.  We could plot `rd` like this

```
Plot[rd, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

But, that's not exactly what we want.  We want to plot `rd` vs `t/tn`.  So, we write a new expression in terms of `tau`, which is `t/tn` and then we plot our new function, like this:

```
rdtau = rd /. t -> tau tn;
Plot[rdtau, {tau, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Okay that's closer, but what about the scale, and dashed line?  Like this

```
Plot[rdtau, {tau, 0, 5},
 PlotRange -> {All, {-2, 2}},
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Red, 
   Line[{{1/2, -2}, {1/2, rdtau /. tau -> 1/2}}]},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

If you want to add labels, etc, please read the documentation and search this site.  Also, study the other answers you get for this question.  Try to understand the different approaches and you will learn a lot.

Comment: Thank you Louis :D